# PowerBI - Pandas isnull().sum() index

Tags: python, pandas, powerbi

I'm running the following Python script in PowerBI

```
# 'dataset' holds the input data for this script
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame(np.sum(dataset.isnull(), axis=0),columns=['Null_Values'])
df['Items']=dataset.isnull().index
```

A few notes:

- simple `dataset.isnull().sum()` does not work as the output is not a DataFrame so is not visible as a table in PowerBI
- If I remove the last line from the snippet above, it works fine but the resulting table in PowerBI is just as follows:

### Null Values

0

0

5

0

4

So you can only guess which column the 5 and 4 refer to. Outside Power BI, `dataset.isnull().sum()` would normally produce

```
            Null Values
Column A      0
Coulmn B      0
Column C      5
Column D      6
```

If I include the last line of the code snippet, I get an error that
`ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index`

I just want to add one more column to describe original column names (Column A, B, C, etc.)

Original dataset:

```
Department,OfficeCode,Sales,Target,Staffing,Dotation
South,23,80,100,0.8,10
South,24,67,100,0.78,15
North,33,111,120,0.98,10
South,25,87,100,,15
West,43,45,50,0.98,10
East,53,65,80,0.89,15
North,34,110,120,,10
North,35,112,120,0.96,15
North,36,,120,0.94,10
North,37,98,120,0.85,15
South,26,77,100,0.7,10
East,54,64,80,0.8,15
East,55,,80,,11
West,44,44,50,,14
East,56,,80,0.79,15
West,44,,50,0.9,16
West,45,34,50,0.89,13
South,27,,100,,14
```

EDIT: OK, I've solved it by changing the last line from:

```
df['Items']=dataset.isnull().index
```

to

```
df['Items']=df.index
```

What it did was to duplicate the index column so it can be seen in the PowerBi Query Editor table.

Perhaps, a follow up question would be how to make PowerBi treat the index column as any other column and display it?

Comment: can you post the `dataset` (at-least a portion of it) also?

Comment: Please add it as text, not as picture.

Comment: That's done now (csv format)